# Concat is not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have table called product, which contains name(nvarchar 1000),

```
P1
P2
P3
P4
```

I have a account table named as accnt_test with product_name.

```
id   name
A1   P1;;p2;;p3;;p4
A2   P1;;p2
A3   P1;;p2;;p3
A4   P1;;p2;;p3;;p4
A5   P1
```

I have to pick those accounts from account table which contains all the products from product table.

so my output should look like:

```
id  name
A1  P1;;p2;;p3;;p4
A4  P1;;p2;;p3;;p4
```

because these two accounts contains all the products from product table.

I have written a query in SQL Server but it is not working.

This is query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM accnt_test ACC
 WHERE ACC.product_name IN
       (SELECT VM.product_name
          FROM (SELECT A.*, P.NAME
                  FROM accnt_test A, product P
                 WHERE A.product_name LIKE
                       CONCAT('%', CONCAT(P.NAME, '%'))) VM
         GROUP BY VM.product_name
        HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT NAME) FROM PRODUCT));
```

so how can it will be used in case of concat .

but SQL Server showing an error:

```
sg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 9
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.
 Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Comment: what version of SQLServer you are using?CONCAT supported only in 2012 and 2014

Comment: You can though use INNER JOIN  to get accounts which have all products in it and then use FOR XML PATH feature of sql to concat products with delimeter. Let me know if you are intrested in this solution

Answer (score 2):

Your code has too many bugs in it. There is no in-built `concat` function in SQL SERVER 2008R2 or previous versions as per MySQL. Try changing your query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   accnt_test ACC
WHERE  ACC.product_name IN (SELECT A.product_name
                            FROM   accnt_test A,
                                   product P
                            WHERE  A.product_name LIKE '%' + P.NAME + '%')
GROUP  BY product_name
HAVING Count(*) = (SELECT Count(DISTINCT NAME)
                   FROM   PRODUCT)
```

Comment: No, there is but in SQL server 2012 onwards. Check MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Rahul yes forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

CONCAT is new to SQL Server 2012. It is not a function on Previous Versions, including 2008 R2.

Use 'fn concat'

```
select {fn concat('%', {fn concat('String', '%')})}
```

Here is the code with 'fn concat'. It will work.

```
SELECT *
  FROM accnt_test ACC
 WHERE ACC.product_name IN
       (SELECT VM.product_name
          FROM (SELECT A.*, P.NAME
                  FROM accnt_test A, product P
                 WHERE A.product_name LIKE
                       {fn concat('%', {fn concat(P.NAME, '%')})}) VM
         GROUP BY VM.product_name
        HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT NAME) FROM PRODUCT));
```

Comment: Why not use the concatenation operator `+`?

Comment: Ya it work. But Here he asks why Concat not working. So, I suggest the {fn concat ('','')} for lower versions.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 'P1' AS NAME INTO #PD 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'P2' AS NAME 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'P3' AS NAME
UNION ALL
SELECT 'P4' AS NAME ;

-- SELECT * FROM #PD; 

SELECT 'A1' AS ID, 'P1;;P2;;P3;;P4' AS PDNAME INTO #ACCS 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'A2' AS ID, 'P1;;P2' AS PDNAM
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'A3' AS ID, 'P1;;P2;;P3' AS PDNAM
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'A4' AS ID, 'P1;;P2;;P3;;P4' AS PDNAM
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'A5' AS ID, 'P1' AS PDNAM ;
 
-- SELECT * FROM #ACCS; 

SELECT XA.* FROM #ACCS XA 
 WHERE XA.ID IN (
        SELECT F.ID FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT temp.id,
                                Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'split_values'
                FROM (
                  SELECT ID, 
                         CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(PDNAME, ';;', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS xml_data  
                    FROM #ACCS
                ) AS temp  CROSS APPLY xml_data.nodes('/M') AS Split(a) 
            ) AP JOIN #PD P ON AP.split_values=P.NAME 
        ) F
        GROUP BY F.ID
        HAVING COUNT(*)= (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT NAME) FROM #PD)
 ); 
 
DROP TABLE #ACCS;
DROP TABLE #PD;
```